# XML: do child nodes inherit parent's namespace prefix?

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

Assume the following XML document:

```
<root xmlns:foo="...">
  <foo:parent>
    <child/>
  </foo:parent>
</root>
```

does `child` element belong to a namespace that corresponds to the prefix `foo`? Just like in case `<foo:child/>`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No. Child nodes *do not* inherit prefixed namespace by default, and explicit prefix addition needed as you mentioned : `<foo:child/>`.

But they *do* inherit ancestor's default namespace (the one without prefix), if any :

```
<root xmlns:foo="...">
  <parent xmlns="bar">
    <child/>
  </parent>
</root>
```

`<parent>` and `<child>` nodes are in the same namespace which URI is `bar`.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Thank you for answering not just the question asked, but also the related non-prefixed version.

Comment: I'd like to add the XML reference document for this :
https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#scoping

(At least this is what I understand from this part)

Comment: @har07 What is your source for this answer?