# do we need to give xml prefix to child tags when it is already provided on the parent level

Tags: xml, apache-camel, xml-namespaces

This is the default camel-context provided in one of the samples.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

   <camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="sampleCamelContext">    
    <camel:route>
      <camel:from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
      <camel:choice>
        <camel:when>
          <camel:xpath>/person/city = 'London'</camel:xpath>
          <camel:log message="UK message"/>
          <camel:to uri="file:target/messages/uk"/>
        </camel:when>
        <camel:otherwise>
          <camel:log message="Other message"/>
          <camel:to uri="file:target/messages/others"/>
        </camel:otherwise>
      </camel:choice>
    </camel:route>
  </camel:camelContext>
</beans>
```

Now since the default ns for `camel:camelContext` is provided, do we need to specify the prefix in the child tags too?

Wouldn't this work? (As alluded in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25789100/1873328)

```
<camel:camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="sampleCamelContext">    
    <route>
      <from uri="file:src/data?noop=true"/>
      <choice>
        <when>
          <xpath>/person/city = 'London'</camel:xpath>
          <log message="UK message"/>
          <to uri="file:target/messages/uk"/>
        </when>        
      </choice>
    </route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Maybe, I do not understand the xml namespaces correctly. Any detail explanation of how namespaces work as a bonus would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two facts give you the answer:

- Child nodes use `xmlns` declaration from the closest parent node.
- The prefix literal (e.g. `camel`) does not matter - the only thing that matters is the namespace it refers to. If different prefixes refer to the same namespace, they can be used interchangingly, and not having a prefix is a prefix too (an empty one).

Because your `xmlns` declaration on `camel:camelContext` refers to the same namespace as the `xmlns:camel` declaration, it does not matter if you omit `camel:` for these child nodes or not, in both cases they will be listed against the `http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring` namespace.

Comment: so, if I understand correctly, because `<camel:camelContext />` has a xmlns defined, the child elements without any prefix will inherit that namespace. So, Can I skip the camel prefix in the `<camel:camelContext />` itself as it already has a xmlns defined

Comment: Yes you can. Or you can leave it as it arguably improves readability.